# Wrong balance between Aerospike instances in cluster

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, key-value-store, aerospike

I have an application with a high load for batch read operations. My Aerospike cluster (v 3.7.2) has 14 servers, each one with 7GB RAM and 2 CPUs in Google Cloud.

By looking at Google Cloud Monitoring Graphs, I noticed a very unbalanced load between servers: some servers have almost 100% CPU load, while others have less than 50% (image below). Even after hours of operation, the cluster unbalanced pattern doesn't change.

Is there any configuration that I could change to make this cluster more homogeneous? How to optimize node balancing?

[image: aerospike instances monitoring graphs]

**Edit 1**

All servers in the cluster have the same identical `aerospike.conf` file:

## Aerospike database configuration file.

```
service {
    user root
    group root
    paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
        paxos-recovery-policy auto-reset-master
    pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
    service-threads 32
    transaction-queues 32
    transaction-threads-per-queue 32
        batch-index-threads 32
    proto-fd-max 15000
        batch-max-requests 200000
}

logging {
    # Log file must be an absolute path.
    file /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log {
        context any info
    }
}

network {
    service {
        #address any
        port 3000
    }

    heartbeat {
                mode mesh
                mesh-seed-address-port 10.240.0.6 3002
                mesh-seed-address-port 10.240.0.5 3002
                port 3002

        interval 150
        timeout 20
    }

    fabric {
        port 3001
    }

    info {
        port 3003
    }
}

namespace test {
    replication-factor 3
    memory-size 5G
    default-ttl 0 # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.
        ldt-enabled true

    storage-engine device {
          file /data/aerospike.dat
          write-block-size 1M
          filesize 180G
        }
}
```

**Edit 2**:

```
$ asinfo
1 :  node
     BB90600F00A0142
2 :  statistics
     cluster_size=14;cluster_key=E3C3672DCDD7F51;cluster_integrity=true;objects=3739898;sub-records=0;total-bytes-disk=193273528320;used-bytes-disk=26018492544;free-pct-disk=86;total-bytes-memory=5368709120;used-bytes-memory=239353472;data-used-bytes-memory=0;index-used-bytes-memory=239353472;sindex-used-bytes-memory=0;free-pct-memory=95;stat_read_reqs=2881465329;stat_read_reqs_xdr=0;stat_read_success=2878457632;stat_read_errs_notfound=3007093;stat_read_errs_other=0;stat_write_reqs=551398;stat_write_reqs_xdr=0;stat_write_success=549522;stat_write_errs=90;stat_xdr_pipe_writes=0;stat_xdr_pipe_miss=0;stat_delete_success=4;stat_rw_timeout=1862;udf_read_reqs=0;udf_read_success=0;udf_read_errs_other=0;udf_write_reqs=0;udf_write_success=0;udf_write_err_others=0;udf_delete_reqs=0;udf_delete_success=0;udf_delete_err_others=0;udf_lua_errs=0;udf_scan_rec_reqs=0;udf_query_rec_reqs=0;udf_replica_writes=0;stat_proxy_reqs=7021;stat_proxy_reqs_xdr=0;stat_proxy_success=2121;stat_proxy_errs=4739;stat_ldt_proxy=0;stat_cluster_key_err_ack_dup_trans_reenqueue=607;stat_expired_objects=0;stat_evicted_objects=0;stat_deleted_set_objects=0;stat_evicted_objects_time=0;stat_zero_bin_records=0;stat_nsup_deletes_not_shipped=0;stat_compressed_pkts_received=0;err_tsvc_requests=110;err_tsvc_requests_timeout=0;err_out_of_space=0;err_duplicate_proxy_request=0;err_rw_request_not_found=17;err_rw_pending_limit=19;err_rw_cant_put_unique=0;geo_region_query_count=0;geo_region_query_cells=0;geo_region_query_points=0;geo_region_query_falsepos=0;fabric_msgs_sent=58002818;fabric_msgs_rcvd=57998870;paxos_principal=BB92B00F00A0142;migrate_msgs_sent=55749290;migrate_msgs_recv=55759692;migrate_progress_send=0;migrate_progress_recv=0;migrate_num_incoming_accepted=7228;migrate_num_incoming_refused=0;queue=0;transactions=101978550;reaped_fds=6;scans_active=0;basic_scans_succeeded=0;basic_scans_failed=0;aggr_scans_succeeded=0;aggr_scans_failed=0;udf_bg_scans_succeeded=0;udf_bg_scans_failed=0;batch_index_initiate=40457778;batch_index_queue=0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0,0:0;batch_index_complete=40456708;batch_index_timeout=1037;batch_index_errors=33;batch_index_unused_buffers=256;batch_index_huge_buffers=217168717;batch_index_created_buffers=217583519;batch_index_destroyed_buffers=217583263;batch_initiate=0;batch_queue=0;batch_tree_count=0;batch_timeout=0;batch_errors=0;info_queue=0;delete_queue=0;proxy_in_progress=0;proxy_initiate=7021;proxy_action=5519;proxy_retry=0;proxy_retry_q_full=0;proxy_unproxy=0;proxy_retry_same_dest=0;proxy_retry_new_dest=0;write_master=551089;write_prole=1055431;read_dup_prole=14232;rw_err_dup_internal=0;rw_err_dup_cluster_key=1814;rw_err_dup_send=0;rw_err_write_internal=0;rw_err_write_cluster_key=0;rw_err_write_send=0;rw_err_ack_internal=0;rw_err_ack_nomatch=1767;rw_err_ack_badnode=0;client_connections=366;waiting_transactions=0;tree_count=0;record_refs=3739898;record_locks=0;migrate_tx_objs=0;migrate_rx_objs=0;ongoing_write_reqs=0;err_storage_queue_full=0;partition_actual=296;partition_replica=572;partition_desync=0;partition_absent=3228;partition_zombie=0;partition_object_count=3739898;partition_ref_count=4096;system_free_mem_pct=61;sindex_ucgarbage_found=0;sindex_gc_locktimedout=0;sindex_gc_inactivity_dur=0;sindex_gc_activity_dur=0;sindex_gc_list_creation_time=0;sindex_gc_list_deletion_time=0;sindex_gc_objects_validated=0;sindex_gc_garbage_found=0;sindex_gc_garbage_cleaned=0;system_swapping=false;err_replica_null_node=0;err_replica_non_null_node=0;err_sync_copy_null_master=0;storage_defrag_corrupt_record=0;err_write_fail_prole_unknown=0;err_write_fail_prole_generation=0;err_write_fail_unknown=0;err_write_fail_key_exists=0;err_write_fail_generation=0;err_write_fail_generation_xdr=0;err_write_fail_bin_exists=0;err_write_fail_parameter=0;err_write_fail_incompatible_type=0;err_write_fail_noxdr=0;err_write_fail_prole_delete=0;err_write_fail_not_found=0;err_write_fail_key_mismatch=0;err_write_fail_record_too_big=90;err_write_fail_bin_name=0;err_write_fail_bin_not_found=0;err_write_fail_forbidden=0;stat_duplicate_operation=53184;uptime=1001388;stat_write_errs_notfound=0;stat_write_errs_other=90;heartbeat_received_self=0;heartbeat_received_foreign=145137042;query_reqs=0;query_success=0;query_fail=0;query_abort=0;query_avg_rec_count=0;query_short_running=0;query_long_running=0;query_short_queue_full=0;query_long_queue_full=0;query_short_reqs=0;query_long_reqs=0;query_agg=0;query_agg_success=0;query_agg_err=0;query_agg_abort=0;query_agg_avg_rec_count=0;query_lookups=0;query_lookup_success=0;query_lookup_err=0;query_lookup_abort=0;query_lookup_avg_rec_count=0
3 :  features
     cdt-list;pipelining;geo;float;batch-index;replicas-all;replicas-master;replicas-prole;udf
4 :  cluster-generation
     61
5 :  partition-generation
     11811
6 :  edition
     Aerospike Community Edition
7 :  version
     Aerospike Community Edition build 3.7.2
8 :  build
     3.7.2
9 :  services
     10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.14:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.27:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.5:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.43:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.30:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.18:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.42:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.33:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.24:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.37:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.41:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.13:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.23:3000
10 :  services-alumni
     10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.42:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.5:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.13:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.14:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.18:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.23:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.24:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.27:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.30:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.37:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.43:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.33:3000;10.0.3.1:3000;10.240.0.41:3000
```

Comment: Did you check the config being the same across those nodes? Can you add the config to the question?

Comment: @RonenBotzer all servers have the same conf file (edited in question)

Comment: Let me know if those config changes have an impact. It may be that the objects aren't as evenly distributed as expected (it's a normal distribution), but that tuning may exacerbate the problem. I'd like to hear how it behaves after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

I have a few comments about your configuration. First, [`transaction-threads-per-queue`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#transaction-threads-per-queue) should be set to 3 or 4 (don't set it to the number of cores).

The second has to do with your batch-read tuning. You're using the (default) [batch-index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/batch.html#batch-index) protocol, and the config params you'll need to tune for batch-read performance are:

- You have `batch-max-requests` set very high. This is probably affecting both your CPU load and your memory consumption. It's enough that there's a slight imbalance in the number of keys you're accessing per-node, and that will reflect in the graphs you've shown. At least, this is possibly the issue. It's better that you iterate over smaller batches than try to fetch 200K records per-node at a time.
- [`batch-index-threads`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#batch-index-threads) – by default its value is 4, and you set it to 32 (of a max of 64). You should do this incrementally by running the same test and benchmarking the performance. On each iteration adjust higher, then down if it's decreased in performance. For example: test with 32, +8 = 40 , +8 = 48, -4 = 44. There's no easy rule-of-thumb for the setting, you'll need to tune through iterations on the hardware you'll be using, and monitor the performance.
- [`batch-max-buffer-per-queue`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#batch-max-buffer-per-queue) – this is more directly linked to the number of concurrent batch-read operations the node can support. Each batch-read request will consume at least one buffer (more if the data cannot fit in 128K). If you do not have enough of these allocated to support the number of concurrent batch-read requests you will get exceptions with error code 152 [`BATCH_QUEUES_FULL`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/client/src/com/aerospike/client/ResultCode.java#L287-L290) . Track and log such events clearly, because it means you need to raise this value. Note that this is the number of buffers **per-queue**. Each batch response worker thread has its own queue, so you'll have `batch-index-threads` x `batch-max-buffer-per-queue` buffers, each taking 128K of RAM. The [`batch-max-unused-buffers`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#batch-max-unused-buffers) caps the memory usage of all these buffers combined, destroying unused buffers until their number is reduced. There's an overhead to allocating and destroying these buffers, so you do not want to set it too low compared to the total. Your current cost is `32 x 256 x 128KB = 1GB`.

Finally, you're storing your data on a filesystem. That's fine for development instances, but not recommended for production. In GCE you can provision either a SATA SSD or an NVMe SSD for your data storage, and those should be [initialized](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/ssd/ssd_init.html), and used as block devices. Take a look at the [GCE recommendations](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/deploy_guides/gce/recommendations) for more details. I suspect you have warnings in your log about the device not keeping up.

It's likely that one of your nodes is an outlier with regards to the number of partitions it has (and therefore number of objects). You can confirm it with `asadm -e 'asinfo -v "objects"'`. If that's the case, you can terminate that node, and bring up a new one. This will force the partitions to be redistributed. This does trigger a migration, which takes quite longer in the CE server than in the EE one.

Comment: I changed batch-max-requests to 30k and transaction-threads-per-queue in one of the servers and I did not noticed any difference. I need to be very careful in changing these values, because I have many large batch requests and I had batch_queues_full problem in the past because of wrong values on these paramenters.

Also, I don't have I/O bottlenecks or disk warnings. I don't use SSD, because they are very expensive compared to normal disks and for my operation I noticed normal disks work well (the problem I described happens also when using SSD)

Comment: I also changed batch-index-threads to 40, 48 and no difference at all

Comment: I meant that you can break down a single large batch-read to several smaller ones, but you've said you hadn't seen the batch change to having an effect.  What is the number of master objects on your nodes?

Comment: I have a replication factor of 3; ~17M master objects in total (~1.2M / server); ~35M replica objects (~2.4M / server); all servers have intense network traffic of 1.6Gbps

Comment: So the number of master objects per-node is about the same? Can you share your AMC (or asinfo) output?

Comment: shared in question text

Comment: I want to see the object distribution on the nodes. Can you do `asadm -e 'asinfo -v "objects"'` and post the output from it?. Also, please grep your log for 'cache-read'. I want to see what the cache hit is on your post-write-queue.

Comment: asinfo -v returned:
10.0.3.1:3000 returned : 4349702
10.240.0.13:3000 returned : 4408342
10.240.0.14:3000 returned : 4379468
10.240.0.24:3000 returned : 4467848
10.240.0.27:3000 returned : 4590624
10.240.0.30:3000 returned : 4473581
10.240.0.33:3000 returned : 4478762
10.240.0.37:3000 returned : 4439411
10.240.0.40:3000 returned : 4048362
10.240.0.42:3000 returned : 4657303
10.240.0.43:3000 returned : 4342455
10.240.0.5:3000 returned : 4455426
10.240.0.6:3000 returned : 4379725

Comment: I updated my answer above with information about forcing a redistribution of partitions. It seems that 10.240.0.40:3000 has significantly less objects than the others. You might want to kill it and bring up a new instance instead.  Also, you might want to increase your [post-write-queue](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#post-write-queue) dynamically, then check if you get a better cache-read hit rate. This assumes you have memory to spare for it. The increase is per-device.

Comment: My application is very specific, I have very few write operations and very fragmented read operations (many reads of many different objects frequently). Do you think post-write-queue change will have any effect? Is there any other better strategy to redistribute objects without killing an outlier node? I suppose Aerospike should be smart enough to detect these nodes unbalance and migrate objects automatically

Comment: Aerospike has a very normal distribution of objects to partitions. The problem happens when in rare cases the number of partitions doesn't end up as even as it should be. There's a JIRA issue open for it, so that's lined up for a fix, but for now the workaround will probably solve the issue. As for the post-write-queue, having more blocks in it might raise your cache-read hit, which would be beneficial. If not, you can always tune it back down. You can do this on a single node for a period and monitor it.

Comment: I did changed the post-write-queue and nothing happened to the cache-read. One curious thing that happened is that I had 12 nodes in the cluster and I restarted 2 hours ago one of these nodes. After this node restart, the cache-read pct dropped to 0.01 in all nodes.

Comment: If your usage pattern doesn't support it, there will not be much of a cache-read hit.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, Aerospike Enterpirse 4.3 introduced 'uniform-balance' which homogeneously balances data partitions. Read more here: https://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-4-3-all-flash-uniform-balance/